# Ati Radeon 5650m fglrx black screen ubuntu (all versions)

Tags: fglrx, ati

I'm trying to install Amd Radeon HD drivers for my Ati 5650m/intel but every time i boot it it doesn't work. My screen is black and i need to remove the fglrx driver section from xorg.conf.
I've checked some forums but hasnt found that my card is compatible with linux drivers.
Sorry for my english.

My system is:
Hp dv7 17.3 laptop
I5 450 2.4 Ghz
6GB Ram
Ubuntu 12.04 64Bit

Thanks.

Comment: There is a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/949641).

Comment: Since this is a bug, we should probably close this as off-topic, in accordance with the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

My laptop is Intel/ati 5650. If the VGA driver use fglrx, the vga option in bios must be changed to "discrete", not "switchable".